# Changing frame content onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 frames, one important frame content displays the welcome page.

On another frame, I have a login page. Now whenever the login is succesful, the home page frame needs to change the content like Welcome User, etc.

I want help with linking one frame to another frame when a button is clicked in JavaScript.

This code diplays the frame in a new window :

```
window.top.location.href="sec.html";
```

I want the `sec.html` frame to be displayed in one particular which is home.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.frames[index].location = 'sec.html';
```

index is 0 based, so in your case its either 0, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not using frames at all 
Instead Read about **ajax with jquery** to achieve the same and it works like Charm!